# Link displays on two lines when adding style

Tags: html, css

Thank you all for your time.

I am trying to do something simple but it turns out to be so complicated.
I need a link to send an email but there's some issue with the style. It shows the content fractured (see jsfiddle). But when I right click several times, everything is back to normal. Any idea?

```css
.sendAll {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sendAll {
    color: white;
    padding: 7% 25%;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sendAll:hover {
    background-color: #0164c6;
}
```

```html
HTML:

<div class="sendAll">
            <a href="#">
                <b id="sendAll">Send Email to All Selected</b>
            </a>
</div>
```

Here's the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4mkmox9v/)

Thank you all !

Comment: looks ok to me on both the fiddle and the code snippet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4mkmox9v/1/

Comment: That is rather peculiar! Declare a `width` rule on the parent and adjust sibling styles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide `display: block` to `#sendAll`

The `<b>` tag provides a `font-weight: bold` property to the element, but the element is not a block level element by itself. So, you have to manually specify the same.

Refer code:

```css
.sendAll {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#sendAll {
  color: white;
  padding: 7% 25%;
  background-color: #0080FF;
  display: block;
}

#sendAll:hover {
  background-color: #0164c6;
}
```

```html
<div class="sendAll">
  <a href="#">
    <b id="sendAll">Send Email to All Selected</b>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
.sendAll {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sendAll {
    color: white;
    padding: 7% 25%;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#sendAll:hover {
    background-color: #0164c6;
}
```

**Explain**
Add a property `white-space:nowrap` in `#sendAll` id

[update code link](https://jsfiddle.net/4mkmox9v/2/)

Comment: This works fine, but still, when you right click on the link, it will move ! I cannot explain how this is so strange

Comment: You can use all the `margin` and `padding` properties in `px` or `em` it will resolved your issue...

Answer (score 0):

if you want your text on only one line, add the following to your `#sendAll` class

```
white-space: nowrap;
```